# Find closed form expression for given power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form, geometric-series

I need to find closed form expressions for these power series F and G:

$a_n = 19^n + n(-5)^n$ for n ..  elements of natural numbers including 0

$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$

and

$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$

**Regarding F(x):**
i tried to split it up in two series and find a solution through geometric series - iam not sure if my approach is correct:

$19^n x^n = (19x)^n$ and $x^nn(-5)^n = n(-5x)^n$

$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (19x)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-5x)^n$

$F(x) = \frac{1}{1-19x} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-5x)^n$

what do i do with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-5x)^n$?

$F(x) = \frac{1}{1-19x} - \frac{5}{(1+5x)^2}$ - is this correct? Really not sure about second part

**Regarding G(x):**

$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$

I am well aware of $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$
but how do i deal with $19^n$ or $n(-5)^n$ in the following:

$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{19^n}{n!}x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(-5)^n}{n!}x^n$

I know this is a lot of questions, but i do hope that someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If $f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n = \frac{1}{1-y}$, then $f'(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ny^{n-1}$, so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ny^n = yf'(y)=\frac{y}{(1-y)^2}$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(ax)^n}{n!}=e^{ax}, \quad \sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(ax)^n}{(n-1)!}=axe^{ax}.$$

Comment: Keep in mind when you take a derivative of a series like $\sum_k x^k$ wrt $x$, the new series has one term less due to the derivative of a constant

Comment: @PavelKozlov using this i got this result: $F(x) = \frac{1}{1-19x} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-5x)^n = \frac{1}{1-19x} + \frac{-5x}{(1+5x)^2}$ Did i do it correctly?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Thank you very much! To all of you, now i understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give here solution to the last example:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{(ax)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(ax)^n}{(n-1)!}
=ax \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(ax)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\stackrel{k=n-1}=
ax \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}=ax e^{ax}.
$$